# What does OptOut really mean in the SMSMessageTracking Data View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

Per the docs:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5

Whether the subscriber has opened out of SMS messages (1 = true, 0 = false)

Is interpreting this to mean the end user clicked on the SMS link correct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [documentation of Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) is incorrect at this point (but that is an assumption of mine).

OptIn and OptOut usually handle subscription stati. If you opted In it tells you that the subscriber does want to receive sms. If a subscriber Opts out it tells you that he does not want to receive the sms, which is kind of identical to an unsub in some points.

This sentence is likely to be wrong from my point of view:

> Whether the subscriber has opened out of SMS messages (1 = true, 0 =
>   false)

It should be

> Whether the subscriber has **opted** out of SMS messages (1 = true, 0 =
>   false)

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming the field OptIn would be able to handle all subscription status changes.

Comment: Bare in mind that this is an assumption of mine. I just created an answer because of the fact that you can write more letters and structure it better than inside a comment. I highly appreciate if someone else backs this up with knowledge and experience or even writes a better answer than mine.

Comment: This is a typo. You can not record an SMS open. this should say opted out. If opt-out is 1 opt-in will be 0